# rxbag segfault on view Image RAW data

Tags: ros, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although it might not be very useful, when I select **Raw** view for an `Image` type topic in rxbag, I get a segfault.

Could somebody confirm this behaviour?

I'm using ros-electric on ubuntu oneiric.
It's happened to me in two different PCs (laptop and desktop, with pretty different hardware but almost the same environment).

BTW, I'm using image_rect_color topics, from the image_pipeline stack, so images should be sane.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** Defect [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5381) created.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28731/rxbag-segfault-on-view-image-raw-data/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-28**:
For debugging a problem like this, a gdb stack backtrace of the segfault is usually needed.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-02-28**:
How do I backtrace rxbag with gdb? I've tried https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Backtrace, but gdb says that rxbag is 'not in executable format: File format not recognized'. I just run 'gdb rxbag' (w/ and w/o args, a .bag file).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-29**:
My mistake. I did not realize `rxbag` was a Python script.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-02-29**:
So, how could I find out what's going on? Do you or somebody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can open a defect ticket, providing all the information you can for the `rxbag` maintainer.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0